# Line chart for multiple Variables

Tags: r, linechart

Following is my dataset:

```
MONTH   YEAR    Load
6   2011    5224.055
7   2011    6073.028
8   2011    5261.029
9   2011    4769.155
6   2012    4865.499
7   2012    5797.578
8   2012    5433.050
9   2012    4482.148
6   2013    4922.000
7   2013    5808.981
8   2013    4928.632
9   2013    4395.204
6   2014    4819.491
7   2014    5258.155
8   2014    4786.323
9   2014    4468.914
6   2015    4931.468
7   2015    5403.063
8   2015    5266.076
9   2015    4803.703
```

Now I want **LOAD on Y-axis**, **Year on X-axis** and line should depict the load and year variation for **each month.** Separate line for separate month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ggplot2` (plus `dplyr` to convert month numbers to month names on the fly), it would be something like this (and we'll assume your data frame is called `dat`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat %>% mutate(MONTH=factor(month.abb[MONTH], levels=month.abb)), 
       aes(x=YEAR, y=Load, colour=MONTH)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,6500)) +
  labs(colour="Month")
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming your dataframe is df):

```
head(df)

MONTH YEAR     Load
1     6 2011 5224.055
2     7 2011 6073.028
3     8 2011 5261.029
4     9 2011 4769.155
5     6 2012 4865.499
6     7 2012 5797.578
```

If you want to show variations per month then use the following:

```
df$MONTH <- as.factor(df$MONTH)
ggplot(df, aes(YEAR, Load, colour = MONTH, group=MONTH, color=MONTH))+
  geom_line(lwd=2) +geom_point()
```

[image]

If you want to show variations per year / month together you can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
df$Date <- as.Date(paste(1, df$MONTH, df$YEAR, sep='/'), '%d/%m/%Y')
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Load, colour = Load))+
  geom_line() +geom_point() + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks= "1 month", date_labels = "%m/%Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]